# How to add confirm form with form alter?

Tags: forms

I would like to add a [confirm form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7) for the edit page of an entity (commerce product in this case), which only appears when an certain form field has a certain value.
I did succeed to set up a confirm form for a custom form as described above, but to add it in a existing form, I guess I have to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).
But I don't understand how to implement it. Can anybody help with in example or some hints, how to start, please?
I tried to implement it with an additional custom submit handler, but it does not work:

```
/**
 * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_FOMRM_ID_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Add custom submit handler
  $form['#submit'][]  = 'MY_MODULE_submit_handler';

}

/**
 * Custom submit handler
 */
function MY_MODULE_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {

  // If a certain field has a certain value add a confirm step
  if ($form_state['field_description']['und'][0]['#description']) == "Something") {
    return custom_misc_form_confirm($form_state);
  }

}

/**
 * Returns the drupal confirmation form
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_confirm(&$form_state) {

  $path = "path/to/form";  
  $title = t('Are you sure you want to to this on %entity?', array('%entity' => drupal_get_title()));

  $text = "A Text";

  // Tell the submit handler to process the form
  $form_state['confirm'] = true;
  return confirm_form($form, $title, $path, $text);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: @leymannx You are right, that makes things easier.